# sqlite3 triggers confusion with OLD and NEW

Tags: triggers, sqlite

What is the difference between OLD.id , NEW.id and just id in sqlite3 triggers?

please help me with this got some explanation which never explained what old and new does

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) says:

> Both the WHEN clause and the trigger actions may access elements of the row being inserted, deleted or updated using references of the form "NEW.*column-name*" and "OLD.*column-name*", where *column-name* is the name of a column from the table that the trigger is associated with.

`id` alone can be used in an SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statement, and refers to a column in one of the tables used in that statement.

Typically, you would use OLD or NEW to find the row in the actual table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ...
BEGIN
    UPDATE MyTable SET UpdateTime = time('now') WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
```